# Design elements

Tags: book-design

Do you know some programs or templates or tips to help me with design elements of a math workbook? For a simple exemple, see picture below and for more I'll show you 2 exemple:

1. [http://www.amazon.com/Thomas-Calculus-Early-Transcendentals-Edition/dp/0321884078](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321884078)
2. [http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Its-Applications-10th-Edition/dp/0321694333/ref=pd_sim_b_10?ie=UTF8&refRID=1Q1S89E37NQENWTWFSDD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321694333)

[image: counter design]

Comment: This needs not simple examples, but what you want. And please keep it related to TeX. You can choose to do this in InDesign and you should seek help elsewhere should you choose to do so.